# determine if a string is absolute URL or relative URL in java

Tags: java, url, relative-url

Given a string, how do I determine if it is an absolute URL or a relative URL in Java? I tried the following code:

```java
private boolean isAbsoluteURL(String urlString) {
    boolean result = false;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        String protocol = url.getProtocol();
        if (protocol != null && protocol.trim().length() > 0)
            result = true;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that all relative URLs (`www.google.com` or `/questions/ask`). are throwing a `MalformedURLException` because there is no protocol defined.

Comment: ... so you catch the exception and return false, indicating that the relative URL is not, in fact, an absolute URL; which is the expected result. So how is that a problem?

Comment: "www.google.com" and "/questions/ask" are not URLs.  They may be absolute or relative URIs, depending on the implied URL scheme.  So this code falls under the category of "works as expected."

Comment: Be aware URL uses your network connection

Comment: `/` is an absolute URL for `file:` but it is relative for `http:`. If you don't know the base URL (acutally, the protocol), you cannot determine the relativeness of the given URL. In your example - `www.google.com` is a relative URL, so your method is correct and specification-compliant in this case, but it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 52):

How about this:

```
final URI u = new URI("http://www.anigota.com/start");
// URI u = new URI("/works/with/me/too");
// URI u = new URI("/can/../do/./more/../sophis?ticated=stuff+too");

if (u.isAbsolute())
{
  System.out.println("Yes, I am absolute!");
}
else
{
  System.out.println("Ohh noes, it's a relative URI!");
}
```

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with [Protocol Urls](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) (urls like //). You can [try it out at IDEOne](http://ideone.com/9AlUkU)

Comment: which can be used to do absolute redirects, [like in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3f0gqvbf/1/)

Comment: note you still have to handle an exception : URISyntaxException. It doesn't seem to bother OP but in my case I would have preferred a true one-liner solution

Comment: @user1075613 `URI.create`

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar you should post this as an answer (else I will do :p) I would vote for you!

Comment: @user1075613 It doesn't stand as a separate answer, because the OP didn't ask how to create a `URI` without throwing checked exceptions. If you post an answer with only that change, it's likely to be downvoted, beginning with me.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390800/determine-if-a-string-is-absolute-url-or-relative-url-in-java/12840255#comment4784889_4390800), you have to normalize the URL before checking it, and that normalization depends on your application, since `www.google.com` is not an absolute URL. Here is an example code, which can be used to check URLs to be absolute:

```
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    String [] urls = {"www.google.com",
                      "http://www.google.com",
                      "/search",
                      "file:/dir/file",
                      "file://localhost/dir/file",
                      "file:///dir/file"};
    
    for (String url : urls) {
      System.out.println("`" + url + "' is " + 
                          (isAbsoluteURL(url)?"absolute":"relative"));
    }
  }

  public static boolean isAbsoluteURL(String url)
                          throws java.net.MalformedURLException {
    final URL baseHTTP = new URL("http://example.com");
    final URL baseFILE = new URL("file:///");
    URL frelative = new URL(baseFILE, url);
    URL hrelative = new URL(baseHTTP, url);
    System.err.println("DEBUG: file URL: " + frelative.toString());
    System.err.println("DEBUG: http URL: " + hrelative.toString());
    return frelative.equals(hrelative);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
~$ java Test 2>/dev/null
`www.google.com' is relative
`http://www.google.com' is absolute
`/search' is relative
`file:/dir/file' is absolute
`file://localhost/dir/file' is absolute
`file:///dir/file' is absolute
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet I use to ensure links are absolute:

```
private String ensureAbsoluteURL(String base, String maybeRelative) {
    if (maybeRelative.startsWith("http")) {
        return maybeRelative;
    } else {
        try {
           return new URL(new URL(base), maybeRelative).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct solution.    `http/foo.html` is a relative URL pointing to the `html` subdirectory but your code would think it is absolute.

Comment: how would your solution look like @StephenOstermiller?

Comment: Other answers here use `URL.isAbsolute()` and that looks like a fine solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

I made this:

```
public static String processUrl(String urlToProcess, String grantedNormalUrl){
    if (urlToProcess.startsWith("//")){
        urlToProcess = checkUrlStartsWithProtocol(urlToProcess);
        return urlToProcess;
    }

    if (!isAbsolute(urlToProcess)){
        String rootPage = extractRootPage(grantedNormalUrl);
        boolean domainEndsWithSlash = rootPage.endsWith("/");
        boolean urlStartsWithSlash = urlToProcess.startsWith("/");
        if (domainEndsWithSlash && urlStartsWithSlash){
            rootPage = rootPage.substring(0, rootPage.length() - 1); // exclude /
        }
        urlToProcess = rootPage + (!(domainEndsWithSlash || urlStartsWithSlash) ? "/" : "") + urlToProcess;
    }

    return urlToProcess;
}

public static boolean isAbsolute(String url){
    if (url.startsWith("//")) { // //www.domain.com/start
        return true;
    }

    if (url.startsWith("/")){ // /somePage.html
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;

    try {
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        result = uri.isAbsolute();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

public static String checkUrlStartsWithProtocol(String url) {
    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        StringBuilder prefixBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        prefixBuilder.append("http:");
        if (!url.startsWith("//")) {
            prefixBuilder.append("//");
        }
        url = prefixBuilder.toString() + url;
    }
    return url;
}

public static String extractRootPage(String urlString) {
    int ignoreSlashes = 0;
    if (urlString.startsWith("http://") || urlString.startsWith("https://")) {
        ignoreSlashes = 2;
    }
    int endPosition = urlString.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < urlString.length(); i++) {
        if (urlString.charAt(i) == '/') {
            if (ignoreSlashes == 0) {
                endPosition = i; // substring exclude /
                break;
            } else {
                ignoreSlashes--;
            }
        }
    }
    return checkUrlStartsWithProtocol(urlString.substring(0, endPosition));
}
```